# How to map a stored procedure using DBContext in ASP.NET MVC 3 Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I do mapping here for tables.. How to map stored procedures here?

```
public class AppDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UserAccount> UserAccount { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GetUserAccounts> GetGetUserAccounts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>().ToTable("UserAccount");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("Customer");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are using EF code-first, perhaps this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6622949/390819

Answer (score 6):

Code first does not support stored procedures.

You can execute scripts in a database initialiser using:

```
string sql = "CREATE PROCEDURE [MyProc]...";
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
```

You can execute procedures them from the context like so:

```
string command = "EXEC MyProc";
IEnumerable<T> results = context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(command, null);
```

Personally, I wrap this up into a nice OO model. I have specialised SP class with strongly typed methods. These methods are decorated with an attribute that tells the DB initialiser to create a stored procedure of a given name from a given source. The strong type methods call the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

add this in **AppDBContext**:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<ResultObject> MyStoredProcedure(string parameter)
        {
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(typeof(ResultObject).Assembly);

            var Param = parameter!= null ?
                new ObjectParameter("Column", parameter) :
                new ObjectParameter("Column", typeof(string));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<ResultObject>("MyStoredProcedure", Param);
        }
```

Add this in **.edmx** file

```
<FunctionImport Name="MyStoredProcedure" ReturnType="Collection(AppDBContext.ResultObject)" >
      <Parameter Name="ZipCode" Mode="In" Type="String" />
      </FunctionImport>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using DB Context and DB First Approach. After creating stored procedures, get to model page in VS and select update Model from Database in right click options in Model page. then in Model Browser > Function Imports select imported SPs and if i want change their names, return values, etc. after all of this i could use SP same as inner methods or other entity classes. for example assume you have an SP that name is "`sp_UserUpdate`" this SP take `userName` and for exam `userAge` as inner parameter and has `res` as out parameter for result status. After importing SP in VS you could use it same as below:

```
System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter pRes = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("res", 0);
db.sp_UserUpdate(userName , userAge , pRes);
```

Hope this help.